# What would be the proper way of implementing "last access time" per row in a table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to analyse the usage of the records in a table and possibly delete stale ones.

Is there a well established pattern (or good practices) for implementing of "last read time" per row in a table?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [PostgreSQL: Last access time to table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/postgresql-last-access-time-to-table). Besides, I would implement such thing temporarily on application level. Or you could activate something like in MySQL "general log" and track the access to each table/row/column.

Comment: This is per table. I need it per row.